# Switching images based on product variation using Espresso

Tags: expresso-store, image, channel-images

I'm using Expresso Store & Channel Images Modules and I want to change the image being shown based on the colour variation chosen by the customer. eg. when selecting the blue shoe a blue show image is shown, when selecting red a red shoe image is shown etc.

I'm sure I can work out a way to do this using a naming convention or such like, but I was hoping someone might be able to suggest a way to do this more natively.

Many thanks

Comment: I think a naming convention is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt there is way to do this natively. You'd need to look at a naming convention to match the variation name to the image as you noted and jQuery to do the switchout.

I have an example on [**a non-Store site**](https://carvedesigns.com/shop/product.php?productid=16884&cat=388&page=1) that may help you get started. The image switch on this site happens when you click on the thumbnails at the bottom left of the product detail.

**[This tutorial offers](http://stuffthatspins.com/2012/04/06/jquery-image-swap-using-form-pull-down-selected-value/)** another way of doing the swap with jQuery.

Here is another tutorial: [**Swaping images in jquery on select dropdown action**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663857/swaping-images-injquery-on-select-dropdown-action)

Comment: Thanks Anna & Justin - i figured it would have to be like that, but just wanted to make sure!

Answer (score 2):

As Anna has mentioned there is not a way to do this by default with the Store tags. You would need to do it with jQuery to swap the images. I would recommend that you use the [Modifier Variable Pair](http://exp-resso.com/docs/store/product_tag.html#modifiers_variable_pair) to output the `option_name` to create an element that you could link with your jQuery. You wouldn't want to use `option_id`as it would be unique for every modifier option in the system.